# Optimizing a value-type like System.UInt32()

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have the following simple value-type:

```
    public struct MyUInt32
    {
        public uint m_value;

        public static implicit operator MyUInt32(UInt32 uInt32)
        {
            return new MyUInt32(uInt32);
        }

        public static implicit operator UInt32(MyUInt32 myUInt32)
        {
            return myUInt32.m_value;
        }

        public MyUInt32(UInt32 uInt32)
        {
            m_value = uInt32;
        }

    }
```

Obviously for the real `System.UInt32` the compiler has some magic way of dealing with the chicken and egg situation where `uint` is an alias to `UInt32` and `UInt32` includes `uint` in it's definition.

I therefore also assume that the compiler has some other tricks to optimize the `System.UInt32` which can be seen in the following comparative tests:

```
MyUInt32 myUInt32= 0;
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i=1;i<int.MaxValue;i++)
{
    myUInt32++;
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time  (implicit): {stopwatch.Elapsed}");

stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    myUInt32.m_value++;
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time (reference): {stopwatch.Elapsed}");

UInt32 uint32 = 0;
stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    uint32++;
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time      (uint): {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
```

Which gives:

```
Elapsed time  (implicit): 00:00:12.4340519
Elapsed time (reference): 00:00:03.5583824
Elapsed time      (uint): 00:00:01.8550149
```

Is there anyway to tell the compiler to optimize `MyUInt32` so it performs like a `System.UInt32` ?

Comment: Was this in Release or Debug? To properly benchmark something you should use a tool like BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: I'd be surprised if current versions of C# aren't able to inline the accessor functions and optimize away any overhead within a trivial loop like that.  Hopefully even remove the whole loop.  But according to https://godbolt.org/z/1b9aGPGKs with .NET 7.0.105 Release build, we get different asm for each loop, the first two keeping the value in memory where store-forwarding latency is part of the bottleneck, the last loop as expected where the value is kept in a register.  The first 2 loops should run about the same (unless one hits the JCC erratum), the last about 6x faster on modern x86.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think about DEBUG vs RELEASE.... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CharlieFace, the answer is simply to compile in RELEASE instead of DEBUG.

```
Elapsed time  (implicit): 00:00:00.7165567
Elapsed time (reference): 00:00:03.7519285
Elapsed time      (uint): 00:00:00.6347374
```